# Validate all objects after renaming a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I use this stored procedure to validate all objects in SQL Server.

This stored procedure uses `sp_refreshsqlmodule` on each object that exists in current database. It works correctly except when I rename a table.

After that all objects that use the renamed table, throw an error but below procedure does not detect these errors.

How can I fix this?

```
DECLARE @NumberRecords INT
DECLARE @RowCount INT
DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Command NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Result int

DECLARE @Names TABLE 
               (
                    [RowId] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
                    [Name]  NVARCHAR(MAX),
                    [Type]  NVARCHAR(MAX)
                )

INSERT INTO @Names
    SELECT
        QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME([Objects].schema_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME([Objects].object_id)) [Name],
        type_desc [Type]
    FROM 
        sys.objects [Objects]
    WHERE 
        type_desc IN ('SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE',
                      'SQL_TRIGGER',
                      'SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION',
                      'SQL_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION',
                      'SQL_INLINE_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION',
                      'VIEW')
    ORDER BY
        [Name]

SET @RowCount = 1
SET @NumberRecords = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Names)

WHILE (@RowCount <= @NumberRecords)
BEGIN
    SELECT @Name = [Name]
    FROM @Names
    WHERE [RowId] = @RowCount

    SET @Command = N'EXEC sp_refreshsqlmodule ''' + @Name + ''''

    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC @Result = sp_executesql @Command

        IF @Result <> 0
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR('Failed', 16, 1)
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            DELETE @Names
            WHERE [RowId] = @RowCount
        END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        -- Nothing
    END CATCH

    SET @RowCount = @RowCount + 1
END

SELECT  
    [Name], [Type]
FROM @Names
```

Comment: As a work around you could use Generate Scripts to dump all your object definitions to text files and then just search them for your old table name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be happy, I have a solution:

```
DECLARE @NumberRecords INT
DECLARE @RowCount INT
DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Command NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Result int
DECLARE @Names TABLE (
    [RowId] INT NOT NULL    IDENTITY(1, 1),
    [Name]  NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [Type]  NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @Names
SELECT
        QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME([Objects].schema_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME([Objects].object_id)) [Name],
        type_desc [Type]
FROM sys.objects [Objects]
WHERE type_desc IN ('SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE',
                    'SQL_TRIGGER',
                    'SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION',
                    'SQL_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION',
                    'SQL_INLINE_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION',
                    'VIEW')
ORDER BY [Name]

SET @RowCount = 1
SET @NumberRecords = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Names)
WHILE (@RowCount <= @NumberRecords)
BEGIN

    SELECT @Name = [Name]
    FROM @Names
    WHERE [RowId] = @RowCount

    SET @Command = N'EXEC sp_refreshsqlmodule ''' + @Name + ''''

    BEGIN TRY

        EXEC @Result = sp_executesql @Command

        IF @Result <> 0
        BEGIN

            RAISERROR('Failed', 16, 1)

        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN

            IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities(@Name, 'OBJECT')
                            WHERE [is_incomplete] = 1))
            BEGIN

                DELETE
                FROM @Names
                WHERE [RowId] = @RowCount

            END

        END

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

        -- Nothing

    END CATCH

    SET @RowCount = @RowCount + 1

END

SELECT  [Name],
        [Type]
FROM @Names
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many oddities in the T-SQL language. When you create or alter a view or a function, SQL Server will not accept the definition you provide if it cannot locate all tables, views, functions that the definition depends upon. You can take this a step further with these objects and specify `WITH SCHEMABINDING` to prevent their dependent objects from being changed whilst the view/function still exists.

For stored procedures, SQL Server will *not* complain about missing tables/views/functions in the definition of the stored procedure<sup>1</sup>. When the procedure starts executing, the server will compile *as much of the code as it can based on objects that currently exist* and start executing. As execution proceeds through the procedure, it may recompile later parts of the procedure based upon objects that *now exist* but didn't before the procedure started executing. This is referred to as "Deferred Name Resolution" and there's no opt out from it (we've been asking for one for years).

It *can* be helpful for writing stored procs that depend upon e.g. temp tables. But it means there's no mechanism to verify *ahead of time* that all objects that a stored procedure references actually exist.

---

<sup>1</sup>It does verify that the definition is *syntactically valid*.